# RegARMA in state space representation

Tags: regression, kalman-filter, state-space-models, armax

I am attempting to fit a state space regression model of the form:

$Y_{t} = i^* + \beta_{1}Y_{t-1} + \beta_{2}X_{t} + \epsilon_{1,t}$

$i^* = i^*_{t-1} + \epsilon_{2,t}$

How could I represent the system above in state-space matrix notation?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose one uses the following notation-formulation for the KF: (there are many).

$Y_t =  F_t^{\prime} \theta_t + \epsilon_t $

$\theta_{t+1} =  G_{t} \theta_{t} + \omega_{t+1} $

$Y_t$ is a scalar , $\theta_t$ is $ n \times 1$, $F_t{^\prime}$ is $1 \times n$,  $\epsilon_t$ is a scalar, $G_t$ is $n \times n $ and $\omega_{t+1}$ is $n \times 1$.

You left the $t$ off of of your $i^{*}$ and I added time subscripting for $\beta$ to clarify what's what. So, you have

$Y_t = i^{*}_t + \beta_{1t} \times Y_{t-1} + \beta_{2t} \times X_t + \epsilon_{1,t} $

$ i^{*}_{t+1} = i^{*}_{t} + \epsilon_{2,t+1} $

The mapping implies that

$F_t^{\prime} = \left(1, Y_{t-1}, X_{t}\right)$,

$\theta_t = \left(i^{*}_{t}, \beta_{1t}, \beta_{2t}\right)^{\prime}$.

Also, notice that $G_t$ is a 3 by 3 matrix with 1's along the diagonal and zero everywhere else.  Also, the $\omega$ elements that correspond to the variances of $\beta_{1t}$ and $\beta_{2t}$ are zero since $\beta_{1t}$ and $\beta_{2t}$ do not evolve over time. Check this carefully because it's late and I could have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much. The trick is to put the lag ($Y_{t-1}$) inside $F_{t}$.

Comment: Yes. You can think of $F_{t}$ as sort of like $X$ matrix in regression. except that $X$ has more than one row because there are multiple observations and everything is done all at once when you do a regression.  In KF, you're kind of doing one row at a time in a sense. $F_t$ kind of contains anything that's known at time $t$.